# Managing state for a loading bar in react with react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, state, infinite-loop

I have an app in React which uses material-ui's responsive drawer component. Let's call it ResponsiveDrawer. In this component I have a state variable called "loading".

```
class ResponsiveDrawer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading:false
        }
        this.setLoading = this.setLoading.bind(this);
    }
    setLoading(loading) {
        this.setState({loading:loading});
    }
    ...
```

I want to display a LinearProgress component at the top of the page, depending on the `loading` state variable.

```
    ...
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={classes.root}>
                {this.state.loading ? <LinearProgress/> : ""} 
                ...
```

Inside ResponsiveDrawer I am also using react router to render some child components.

```
                ...
                <main className={classes.content}>
                    <div className={classes.contentWrapper}>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route
                                exact
                                path="/investments"
                                component={InvestmentsComponent}
                            />
                            ...
                        </Switch>
                     </div>
               </main>
          </div>
```

Inside Investments component, I am doing a fetch from an API.
What I would like to do, is to set the loading state in the ResponsiveDrawer component to `true` and then set it back to `false` upon successful fetch.

So I passed the setLoading function of the ResponsiveDrawer into InvestmentsComponent as props:

```
 InvestmentsComponent = <Investments setLoading={this.setLoading} />
```

And then tried to set it to true on `componentDidMount()`

```
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.setLoading(true);
        fetchInvestments(); // sets loading to false upon completion
    }

     fetchInvestments() {
        fetch("/api/investments", {
            credentials: "same-origin",
            headers: {
                "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
            }
        })
            .then(res => {
                if (!res.ok) throw Error(res.status);
                return res.json();
            })
            .then(responseJson => {
                this.props.setLoading(false);
                this.setState({ investments: responseJson });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error("Unable to fetch investments"); // show error message
            });
    }
```

However, when I do this, react goes into infinite loop - I assume that when the state of `loading` changes, it also reloads the investments component route which then sets the loading state again.

I end up with:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
>   repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
>   componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
>   prevent infinite loops.

What could be a potential solution to this conundrum?

Comment: Can you show the fetchInvestments() code?

Comment: I edited the post, however the actual culprit of the infinite loop is the setState in componentDidMount.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think the ideal solution would be to do the fetching in the parent component, then pass the response to the `InvestmentsComponent`. This way, `InvestmentsComponent` only have the responsibility of displaying the response. The parent's component can fetch the data and set its own state accordingly.

Comment: @Jackyef thanks, I thought about it too but that solution does not fully satisfy me. ResponsiveDrawer will eventually contain routes to many components. I suppose that managing every API call in it would quickly become a nightmare. Do you perhaps know if something like Redux could help with managing the state?

Comment: If that's the case, you can simply wrap `InvestmentsComponent` in another component, let's call it `InvestmentsWrapper`. That component will be the one doing the fetching and then pass it down to `InvestmentsComponent`. Your `ResponsiveDrawer` can then just render the wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved the issue by rendering the route component in a different way, by using `render` instead of `component` prop

```
 <Route exact path="/investments" render={InvestmentsComponent} />
```